# How to use hasRole in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, authorization

I wrote SpringBoot application with authentication via web login form. Class **WebSecurityController** is responsible for authentication and authorization.
Here is its code:

```
@Controller
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityController extends WebSecurityConfiguration {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/users/getAll").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")  
  .anyRequest().permitAll()
  .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .usernameParameter("name").passwordParameter("password")
  .and()
    .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout") 
   .and()
   .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
  .and()
    .csrf();
 }

 @Autowired
 public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
      .usersByUsernameQuery("select name,password,enabled from users where name=?")
      .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?")
      .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
 }

}
```

It retrieves the user credentials from **users** and **user_roles** tables of the database:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+--------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | name   | salary  | enabled | password                                                     |
+----+--------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Rinat  |  100000 |       1 | $2a$10$Md.HmF6dVbwKLxcb09dgy.JTHKq3BLLg0ZrBHHx75fNmkH8.kGeGy |
|  2 | Juliya | 1000000 |       1 | $2a$10$XWksiqEwqJ4jWp00F37i/.A8YpknUPKi36kDd2NgwKI6EBPRRMzXa |
+----+--------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select * from user_roles;
+----+----------+------------+
| id | username | role       |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | Rinat    | ROLE_ADMIN |
|  2 | Juliya   | ROLE_USER  |
+----+----------+------------+
```

Authentication works fine, but unfortunately any users can access to protected resource "/users/getAll". It seems that `access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"` not working.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I repair the method `configure()` and extends from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as it said in Spring Security reference [6.4 Authorize Requests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authorize-requests):

```
@Controller
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityController extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     
     http
        .authorizeRequests()                                                                
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()                  
            .antMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
            .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")            
            .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   
        .and()
            .formLogin()
        .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout") 
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            ;
}
     
@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
      .usersByUsernameQuery("select name,password,enabled from users where name=?")
      .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?")
      .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE and Spring Security 5.0.7.RELEASE and in my WebSecurityController I'm using the method `hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')`.

Here is a fix example:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.authorizeRequests()
  // old
  //.antMatchers("/users/getAll").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN") 
  //.anyRequest().permitAll() 
  // Update    
  .anyRequest().permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/users/getAll").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN") 
  .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .usernameParameter("name").passwordParameter("password")
  .and()
    .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout") 
   .and()
   .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
  .and()
    .csrf();
 }
```

Comment: I've just tried your solution, unfortunately not working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: the problem is "AnyRequest().permitAll() is after the hasAuthority(Admin).
it will overwrite the access  i will update the code ^^ hope it works for you