# Spring boot admin page - Security config - Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

im my web application, i have ad admin page.

the security config looks like this:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers( 
             "/registration**",
                "/js/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/img/**"
               , "/oauth_login")
    .permitAll() 
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()                      
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .clearAuthentication(true)
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll()
    .and()

    .oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint().userService(customOAuth2UserService).and()
            .tokenEndpoint()
            .accessTokenResponseClient(authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient())
            .and()
    .loginPage("/oauth_login").permitAll();
}
```

I would like to do something like:
for the users who are admins (has the role: ROLE_ADMIN)
can access the page: /adminPage

but i fail to add it to my securityConfig class

also is there anything i should be doing in my html code knowing that im using thymeleaf?

regards

Comment: Did u try ```.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")``` . The ROLE_  prefix is automatically added

Comment: @sahit yes it gives me 403 error =\  and nothing happen

Comment: You can check example here, for better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825679/how-to-use-hasrole-in-spring-security