# Why won't Spring Boot redirect to Keycloak login page on 403?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I'm trying to setup a Spring Boot api with authentication provided by Keycloak (separate instance).  All running in a local docker swarm/compose.  Trouble is that when I direct the user to /api/v3/login, which is gated by `@RolesAllowed("ROLE_USER")`, I get back the standard whitelabel error page with the message `There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403)`.  I'm expecting the browser to be directed to the Keycloak client login page.

Setup below.

ApplicationConfiguration - This is done so we pull the Keycloak client configuration from a database instead of the config file.  We'll have multiple clients depending on the user's email domain (which is provided to us via a cookie):

```
@ComponentScan({"com.mycompany"})
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.mycompany")
@EntityScan("com.mycompany")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    ...
    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new CustomKeycloakConfigResolver();
    }
}
```

CustomKeycloakConfigResolver:

```
public class CustomKeycloakConfigResolver implements KeycloakConfigResolver {
    @Autowired
    private KeycloakConfigService keycloakConfigService;
    ...
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public KeycloakDeployment resolve(final HttpFacade.Request request) {
        HttpFacade.Cookie cookie = request.getCookie("authDomain");
        if (cookie == null) {
            return generateNullDeployment();
        }
        
        final Pageable defaultPaging = PageRequest.of(0,1,Sort.by("id").ascending());
        Page<KeycloakConfig> page = keycloakConfigService.readConfigsByFilter(
            "domain", cookie.getValue(), defaultPaging
        );
        
        if ((page == null) || (page.getContent().size() < 1)) {
            return generateNullDeployment();
        }

        KeycloakConfig config = page.getContent().get(0);
        AdapterConfig adapterConfig = new AdapterConfig();
        adapterConfig.setRealm(config.getRealm());
        adapterConfig.setResource(config.getResource());
        adapterConfig.setPublicClient(config.getIsPublic());
        adapterConfig.setAuthServerUrl(config.getAuthServerUrl());
        adapterConfig.setSslRequired(
                config.getIsSslRequired() ? "all" : "none"
        );
        adapterConfig.setUseResourceRoleMappings(
                config.getUseResourceRoleMappings()
        );
        adapterConfig.setTokenStore(config.getTokenStore());
        adapterConfig.setBearerOnly(config.getBearerOnly());

        KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeployment =
                KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(adapterConfig);

        LOGGER.info("Keycloak Deployment Realm:    {}", keycloakDeployment.getRealm());
        LOGGER.info("Keycloak Deployment Resource: {}", keycloakDeployment.getResourceName());
        LOGGER.info("Keycloak Deployment URL:      {}", keycloakDeployment.getAuthUrl());

        return keycloakDeployment;
    }
```

Note - this all appears to be working, although on a single call this resolve method gets called dozens of times:

```
...
o.k.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver      : Keycloak Deployment Realm:    SpringBootKeycloak
o.k.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver      : Keycloak Deployment Resource: SpringBootKeycloak
o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Loaded URLs from http://auth-service:8080/auth/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/.well-known/openid-configuration
...
o.k.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver      : Keycloak Deployment Realm:    SpringBootKeycloak
o.k.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver      : Keycloak Deployment Resource: SpringBootKeycloak
o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Loaded URLs from http://auth-service:8080/auth/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/.well-known/openid-configuration
...
```

Anyway, at the end, we have a valid KeycloakDeployment, with http://auth-service:8080/auth as a auth login URL.

The app's security configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration
        extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests();
...
```

So all requests are authorized.  The API endpoint is:

```
...
    @RolesAllowed("ROLE_USER")
    @GetMapping(
            value = "/login",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> login() {
        final Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
        response.put("status", "OK");
        return response;
    }
...
```

So really I'm just looking to see if the user is authenticated or not.

Now - what I'm expecting to happen is that the user comes in, isn't authenticated, and gets directed to the Keycloak login page.  Instead, I just get the 403 Forbidden white label page.

I assume this is because in the security config I use `.authorizeRequests()`, and that gives the user an "Anonymous" role even if they aren't authenticated.  But for the life of me I can't seem to get the right combination of calls so that when a user hits that login endpoint and isn't actually logged in, they will be directed to the KeycloakDeployment's login page.

---

Update:  I think I've solved part of this mystery.

I had an old AuthenticationEntryPoint class on the classpath

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint
        implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
```

Even though I never specified it with .authenticationEntryPoint(), Spring Boot magic autoconfiguration seemed to have found it and was using it.

I've disabled it fully, and now I am at least getting redirected from /api/v3/login to /sso/login.  However /sso/login is no longer using the `CustomKeycloakConfigResolver`, which is important because without that we have no KeycloakDeployment, which means we fail with the exception

```
rest-api_1            | 2021-12-02 21:59:20.871  WARN 12 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Failed to load URLs from null/realms/null/.well-known/openid-configuration
rest-api_1            |
rest-api_1            | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host is null
rest-api_1            |     at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.notNull(Asserts.java:52) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
```

Comment: Can you do a small test? Does it work when you configure explicitly in the SecurityConfiguration:
`http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").hasRole("ROLE_USER")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();`

Comment: Also, check if the role name is identical in your Keycloak and the role is assigned to the user. Sometimes it could be just overlooked.

Comment: Had to change the hasRole to `.hasRole("USER")` or startup fails (exception that role shouldn't start with "ROLE_" since it is already assumed).  But still the same result.  I don't thin the name will matter - since I'm never directed to the Keycloak login page, I never get as far as having a JWT with any role.   But I did double check anyway.

Comment: What would happen, if you changed the role name the same way to `@RolesAllowed("USER")`?

Comment: I have a working example with Keycloak and it redirects properly. However, I put all my permissions in my `ConfigurerAdapter` class and not in annotations like you. If you are interested, I can post a sample as an answer, let me know!

Comment: Seems I had an old custom AuthenticationEntryPoint that was being picked up by Spring magic.  Not the end of the issue though, because with this removed I get redirected to /sso/login as I would expect, but then that gets blocked because it is no longer using the CustomKeycloakConfigResolver that we need.  Happy to see a working example if you have it.

Comment: Does the example below help in any way? Maybe you could try and comment out your @RolesAllowed annotations and test if using the SecurityConfigururerAdapter works. You can then narrow down the cause. I am interested to see the solution myself because I like the annotations better, personally.

Comment: Thanks @roccobaroccoSC .  The annotations themselves aren't a problem, although to be honest I'm not sure what is.  Spring is providing a few too many ways to skin a cat, and they don't all seem to play well with each other.  Anyway - to get the annotations working you just need the annotation `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)` on the security configuration class, and that's working.  I ended up stripping everything and starting from scratch again on the rest API and it's working, although we'll see when I hit a problem again adding stuff back in.

Comment: Yeah, I like this aproach. Add stuff incrementally and test. Please do share the solution when you have it. GL

Answer (score 1):

As requested, I am sharing my configuration (anonymized). The difference is, the authorization mappings are in the `SecurityConfigurerAdapter` and not in annotations like yours.

```java
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakSecurityComponents;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;

// https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak#securityconfig
// https://newbedev.com/when-to-use-spring-security-s-antmatcher

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
class MyAppWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    private static final String COM_MY_COMPANY_MY_APP_SERVER_SECURITY_DISABLED = "com.mycompany.myapp.server.security.DISABLED";
    
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    
    // Tasks the SimpleAuthorityMapper to make sure roles are not prefixed with ROLE_.
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver()
    {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy()
    {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(http);

        if (isDisabled())
        {
            // Only for debugging purposes. Keycloak is off!
            
            // Starting server with security off:
            // mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dcom.mycompany.myapp.server.security.DISABLED=true"
            
            log.warn("STARTING WITHOUT WEB-SECURITY. ONLY FOR DEBUGGING!!!");
            log.warn("STARTING WITHOUT WEB-SECURITY. ONLY FOR DEBUGGING!!!");
            log.warn("STARTING WITHOUT WEB-SECURITY. ONLY FOR DEBUGGING!!!");
            
            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                ;
        }
        else
        {
            // Production
            log.info("PRODUCTION MODE. Security is on.");

            // Docu: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/
            // Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825679/how-to-use-hasrole-in-spring-security
            http
            .authorizeRequests()                                                                
                .antMatchers(
                    "/resources/**",
                    "/about",
                    "/error",
                    "/sso/login",
                    "/lobby",
                    "/sandbox/**"
                ).permitAll()                  
                .antMatchers("/component/admin").hasRole("myapp-manager")
                .antMatchers("/component/**").hasRole("myapp-user")
              //.antMatchers("/dbadmin").access("hasRole('myapp-user') and hasRole('myapp-db-admin')") // matching of >1 role
                .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   
            .and()
                .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler())
                .logoutUrl("/sso/logout").permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/lobby")
            //.and()
            //    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
                ;
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private boolean isDisabled()
    {
        String x = System.getProperty(COM_MY_COMPANY_MY_APP_SERVER_SECURITY_DISABLED);

        log.debug("isDisabled: Системно свойство {}={}", COM_MY_COMPANY_MY_APP_SERVER_SECURITY_DISABLED, x);
        return "true".equals(x);
    }

}
```

And there is a Servlet I created for debugging and testing the configuration. It is used to log in/out and redirect to a couple of resources to test the authorization.

```java
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.keycloak.AuthorizationContext;
import org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class LobbyController {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK )
    @GetMapping(path = "/lobby", produces = "text/html")
    public String lobby(Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        log.debug("lobby");
        log.trace("lobby: request.getAttributeNames: {}", Collections.list(request.getAttributeNames()));
        
        String info = ""; 

        CsrfToken _csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf");
        log.debug("_csrf: {}, {}", _csrf.getParameterName(), _csrf.getToken());
        
        KeycloakSecurityContext keycloakSecurityContext = (KeycloakSecurityContext) request.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());
        boolean isLoggedIn = keycloakSecurityContext != null;
        
        if (isLoggedIn)
        {
            KeycloakAuthenticationToken keycloakPrincipal = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) principal;
            SimpleKeycloakAccount details = (SimpleKeycloakAccount) keycloakPrincipal.getDetails();
            
            info
                = "<PRE>"
                
                + "<B>You are logged in.<B><BR/>"
                + "Realm: " + keycloakSecurityContext.getRealm() + "<BR/>"
                + "TokenString                : <input value='" + keycloakSecurityContext.getTokenString() + "'/><BR/>"
                + "IdTokenString              : <input value='" + keycloakSecurityContext.getIdTokenString() + "'/><BR/>"
                + "IdToken.Type               : " + keycloakSecurityContext.getIdToken().getType()             + "<BR/>"
                + "IdToken.Subject            : " + keycloakSecurityContext.getIdToken().getSubject()          + "<BR/>"
                + "IdToken.Id                 : " + keycloakSecurityContext.getIdToken().getId()               + "<BR/>"
                + "IdToken.getAccessTokenHash : " + keycloakSecurityContext.getIdToken().getAccessTokenHash()  + "<BR/>"
                + "IdToken.Email              : " + keycloakSecurityContext.getIdToken().getEmail()            + "<BR/>"
                + "IdToken.Name               : " + keycloakSecurityContext.getIdToken().getName()             + "<BR/>"
                + "IdToken.PreferredUsername  : " + keycloakSecurityContext.getIdToken().getPreferredUsername()+ "<BR/>"
                + "principal                  : <textarea>" + principal.toString() + "</textarea><BR/>"
                + "principal.details.principal: " + details.getPrincipal() + "<BR/>"
                + "principal.details.roles    : " + details.getRoles() + "<BR/>"

                + "</PRE>"
                ;

            AuthorizationContext authzContext = keycloakSecurityContext.getAuthorizationContext();
            if (authzContext!=null)
                info 
                    += "<PRE>"

                    + "authzContext.hasResourcePermission(/lobby)           : " + authzContext.hasResourcePermission("/lobby")            + "<BR/>"
                    + "authzContext.hasResourcePermission(/component/person): " + authzContext.hasResourcePermission("/component/person") + "<BR/>"
                    + "authzContext.hasResourcePermission(/component/admin) : " + authzContext.hasResourcePermission("/component/admin")  + "<BR/>"
                    + "authzContext.hasScopePermission(email)               : " + authzContext.hasScopePermission("email")                + "<BR/>"
    
                    + "</PRE>"
                    ;
        }
        else
        {
            info 
                = "<PRE>"
                + "<B>You are logged out.<B><BR/>"
                + "</PRE>"
                ;
        }
        
        info
            += "<A href='/component/person'>Person component</A><BR/>"
            + "<A href='/component/admin'>Admin component</A><BR/>"
            + "<A href='/sandbox/foo'>Sandbox</A><BR/>"
        ;
        
        if (isLoggedIn)
            info += "<FORM method='POST' action='/sso/logout'><input type='hidden' name='" + _csrf.getParameterName() + "' value='" + _csrf.getToken() + "' /><input type='submit' value='Log out'/></FORM><BR/>";
        
        return info;
    }

}
```